# Remove parameters from SQL Query in with Regex / LogStash

Tags: sql, regex, ruby, logstash

A 3rd party system I use logs all SQL queries along with rowcount & response time which I then send to Logstash/Elastic to calculate metrics. As this system doesn't use bind variables, and there are 10's of millions of queries a day, I need to be able to rollup the data, which I can't do if the majority of queries are unique. I need a way to replace the SQL query parameters with '?' as Oracle would do via Cursor Sharing.

i.e.

replace

```
'SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = 123'
```

with

```
'SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = ?'
```

I have access to Ruby scripting magic in Logstash, but unfortunately all of the google results for 'sql regex' or similar return results of how to use regular expressions in SQL, not the other way round. Before I go crafting a regular expression parser, I thought I would check in here to see if others have tried to solve a similar problem.

FYI, have looked at implementing a solution using a Ruby SQL AST library such as https://github.com/lfittl/pg_query but plugging Ruby libraries in to Logstash becomes more of a problem of writing a custom Filter plugin to do the work, which may be the answer, but i'm hoping I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Comment: I have tried researching the best way to approach the problem, but unfortunately by queries for methods of editing SQL query strings have returned results on SQL syntax itself rather than how to interpret it, hence I'm reaching out here.

Comment: Have a try with: [demo](https://regex101.com/r/poJSBf/1). I'm not sure ruby supports `\K` but there're other ways to do the job. This regex replace every `id = numerics` with `id = ?` within SQL `select * from ...`, if you have other cases, please, edit your question and add more tests cases and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a logstash/ruby developer/user, but in terms of regular expression you may try this one:

> (=\s\W\w+\W|=\s\d+)

You can test this [here](https://regex101.com/r/c4IHzl/1)

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Column1 = 1
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Column1 = 'abc'
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE (Column1 = 'abc' OR Column2 = 1)
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE (Column1 = 'abc' AND Column2 = 1) OR Column2 = 'zxy'
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE (Column1 = 'abc' AND Column2 = 1) OR Column2 = 'zxy' AND 
Column3 = 2
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Column1 = 1 AND Column2 = 2
```

**Expected Results:**

```
Match 1
Full match  = 1
Group 1.    = 1

Match 2
Full match  = 'abc'
Group 1.    = 'abc'

Match 3
Full match  = 'abc'
Group 1.    = 'abc'

Match 4
Full match  = 1
Group 1.    = 1

Match 5
Full match  = 'abc'
Group 1.    = 'abc'

Match 6
Full match  = 1
Group 1.    = 1

Match 7
Full match  = 'zxy'
Group 1.    = 'zxy'

Match 8
Full match  = 'abc'
Group 1.    = 'abc'

Match 9
Full match  = 1
Group 1.    = 1

Match 10
Full match  = 'zxy'
Group 1.    = 'zxy'

Match 11
Full match  = 2
Group 1.    = 2

Match 12
Full match  = 1
Group 1.    = 1

Match 13
Full match  = 2
Group 1.    = 2
```

Based on these results you can create a function to replace the value of '= 2' to '= ?'.

Hope that it at least gives you a starting point.